# passing array from controller to webservice

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc

I am passing a array from my jquery to controller.
I have the following function in jquery

```
function UpdateWeeklySalesReport_Clicked(AccName,HighComm) {
  alert("function called");
  var isChecked = $('table#HighlightsArea input#SelectHighlights').is(':checked');
  alert('' + isChecked);
  var HighlightsArea = [];
  var count = $('table#HighlightsArea input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
  alert(''+count);
  if (isChecked)
  {

    for(i=0;i=count;i++)
    {
      var row = $(this).closest('tr');
      var AccName=row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text();
      var HighComm=row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text();
      HighlightsArea[0][AccountName] ;AccName;
      HighlightsArea[0][HighlightsComments] ;HighComm;
      HighlightsArea.push({ AccountName: AccName, HighlightsComments: HighComm });    
    }
  }

  $('[name="SelectHighlights"]:checked').each(function() {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');                                
    var item = {
        AccountName: row.find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
        HighlightsComments: row.find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
    };

    HighlightsArea.push(item);
  });

  //HighlightsArea.push({ AccountName: AccName, HighlightsComments: HighComm });

  GetPartialView(
    GetRootPath() + "/WeeklySales/FianlDraft",    //URL
    JSON.stringify(HighlightsArea), //Data:  
    WeeklySalesSucceeded  //Success
  );

  var from = $('#FromDate').text();
  //alert('' + from);
  var to = $('#ToDate').text();
  //var row = $('#HighlightsArea tr').filter(':has(:checkbox:checked)').find('td').text();
  //alert('row'+row);
  $('#FinalFromDate').html(from);
  $('#FianlToDate').html(to);
  //$('#HighlightsArea').

  $('#FianlDraftTabHeader').removeClass('HideThis');
  $('#enclosure').tabs('select', 3);
}
```

In my controller I need to handle the array to pass the array to webservice.

Comment: Hey, what does `GetPartialView` do? Does it just pass the stringified `HighlightArea` to the URL specified?

Comment: Also, what does the JSON object look like when you post it?

Comment: function GetPartialView(url, data, onSuccess) {
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        data: data,
        success: onSuccess,
        error: GenericErrorHandler,
        contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
        dataType: 'html',
        type: 'GET'
    });
}
This is my GetPartialView function

Comment: Hey @user1921917, so I see you posted another question related to your previous question. Sorry I missed your comment there. Anyway, in connection to your previous question, are you wanting to post from jquery to your controller? Or you already received your data in your controller and you want to submit to a webservice? Which one is your issue?

Comment: I want to pass data from jquery to controller and from controller to web service
I require both these things to be done 
Please help me out 
Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 0):

What is your method controller method receiving? Is your method controller responding to a Post verb, it seems that your ajax call is trying to call your controller using "GET". Get method passes the data through URL. So if you're sending an array, I hardly recommend to use "POST" on your ajax method. You still can return on your method the Partial View that you want to render to client. Here's some example:

```
public Class MyCustomList 
{
   //Class to wrap the array
   public string[] ArrayProp;
}
```

**Your controller Method**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult GetView(MyCustomList list)
{
   //handle the list
   return PartialView("MyPartialView");
}
```

**Your javascript**

```
var listToSend = {};
listToSend.ArrayProp = ["hello", "world"]; //dummy Data
$.ajax({
   url: "/Controller/GetView",
   data: JSON.stringify(listToSend),
   contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
   dataType: 'html', 
   type: 'POST',
   sucess: function (data) {
       //data should be your view html
   },
   error: ErrorHandler 
});
```